# WPF ListView groups repeat column headers

Tags: wpf, listview, expander, collectionviewsource

Is there a way to repeat the column headers inside each group of a ListView.GridView when using a grouped CollectionViewSource as the source of the ListView?

I am using the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754027.aspx which uses an Expander control to display each group.

I would like the column headers to appear inside the expander for each group instead of at the top of the ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you may be able to include GridViewHeaderRowPresenters inside your group headers:

```
<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
  DataContext="{Binding View, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ListView,1}}"
  Columns="{Binding Columns}"
  ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding ColumnHeaderContainerStyle}"
  ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding ColumnHeaderTemplate}"
  ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector}"
  AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding AllowsColumnReorder}"
  ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding ColumnHeaderContextMenu}"
  ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding ColumnHeaderToolTip}"
  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
```

If that doesn't work, one sure-fire way to do it is to add a Rectangle that is painted with a VisualBrush that references the one-and-only GridViewHeaderRowPresenter at the top of the GridView.

This can be done with an attached property to be used on the Rectangle.  When the attached property is set, it registers a low priority Dispatcher callback that:

1. Scans up the visual tree to the ListView
2. Searches down until it finds the GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
3. Construct a VisualBrush and sets it as the Fill for the Rectangle, and

The Rectangle itself would be something like this:

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Height="{Binding Fill.Visual.RenderHeight}"
           my:GridViewHeaderHelper.SearchForHeaderRowPresenterAndSetFill="True" />
```

Comment: Ray, thank you very much, this is perfect! You can't really ask for much more than this from an answer, I copied the XAML into my group style and it worked right away. Quality.

Btw, I'm glad using the GridViewHeaderRowPresenter in my group headers did the trick, because the second solution you offered seemed quite a bit more involved...